# Mass Effect question on New Game + romance

Tags: mass-effect-3

Just completed ME3 last night and have a question going forward for my + playthrough. Any idea which romance you are attached to at the start? My save import going into ME3 had a Liara ME1 and a Miranda ME2 romance. I tried to keep both of those going in ME3 but it ended my relationship with Miranda once I paramoured with Liara (tear). So now going forward in new game + I'm thinking I either want to go Miranda or Ashley till the end. Is that possible?

Comment: You got Ashley? Lucky you, I've been stuck with Kaidan for years now. And I truly and utterly despise the guy. I really need to dig up that Virmire savegame.

Answer (score 5):

A new game+ is not in any way different from a regular import when it comes to romance. You will have the relationships that were imported from ME2.

Comment: Sweet. I just want to make sure it's my ME2 and not my ME3 romance.